# Disable Manual Zooming on UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, zooming

I have a project with a UIScrollView which I want to control the zooming programmatically but not via user interaction.  I have tried setting the `multipleTouchedEnabled` property to false.  This doesn't work.  When I pinch on the scroll view, the `scrollViewDidZoom` and `viewForZoomingInScrollView` are called.  I have also tried subclassing UIScrollView and overriding `addGestureRecognizer` and disabling the gesture which passes a `[gesture [isKindOfClass: [UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]`.  After breakpointing on that override, no gestures are matched.

So how can I have zooming on the scroll view but not allow manual interaction with the zooming.  I still need single finger panning for normal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;